# How to describe complex shots in spec script?

Tags: screenwriting

I know we must be lean with these, to keep scenes legible and flowing, but I absolutely have/need to describe certain (quite complex) shots in my script! For example...

How can I describe this scene, in formatting terms, which starts with a MACRO close up of animal skin (texture) pulling out to reveal the whole animal, then further back to reveal a man standing nearby - as one continuous shot?? 
E.g. MACRO / CLOSE ON / CLOSE UP / ZOOM OUT / PULL BACK / REVEAL etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't always have to use the technical terms; even Tarantino and Sorkin don't. Just say:

We see a close up of animal skin, we can see the texture and fur. The camera pulls back to reveal the whole animal, then further back to reveal a MAN standing nearby. This is a continuous shot.

What matters more than technicality is story, bar none. If your story is good, and well told--like you said, lean, concise--then they will look past the technical deficiencies.

Comment: +1: The script you submit is *not* the shooting script.